# which one to choose for future , c++ or python2.x/3.x

Tags: c++, python, c

since last four years i had been coding in c/c++, but those lenthy programs made me sick of them.

then i got to know about python, and i have learned the basics.

python seams to be more flexible and powerful than c++...

**But i want to know is python realy better than c++?
if yes/no in what ways , please explain.**

since i am a student , **practicing which language would fetch me better job?**

Comment: Python is not better and not worse than C++. It's different. The way you have posed this question is subjective and argumentative, so it will probably be closed.

Comment: better for what? more powerful for doing what? The answer is probably python in either case but I find it hard to imagine writing an OS in python for example.

Comment: Subjective and vague: better how? For programming smartphone apps? For writing data-driven web apps? For building an operating system? I can't help but feel that this is a lazy question.

Comment: A `Car` is better than `C++`, because `C++` can't drive you to and from work.

Comment: They're both Turing Complete, so neither is more powerful than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is completely different than C/C++, so it's hard to compare. Python lets you write clear, concise programs and very quickly develop software at the price of performance. It lets you be very productive and in many cases program performance is less concern, than programmer performance.

There are many existing programs for python `2.*`, so it's better to stick for now with it. It would be fairly easy to move to `3.*` later on.

Comment: u made the thing a bit clear.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on your needs, Python isn't replacing C/C++ in the embedded space anytime soon, and not too many web frameworks are going to be based on C/C++.

Python is neither better nor worse, or neither more or less flexible or powerful than C++. it's just aimed at a different set of problems.

I would rather students start at something like C++ so they have a better understanding of things like pointers & memory management. It's not really objects all the way down.